# Is Tornado.WebSocketHandler.on_message guarantee receive a whole message, nothing more or less?

Tags: websocket, tornado

I was worried about the fragmentation. Not sure whether Tornado.WebSocketHandler.on_message receive a whole message or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `on_message` will always receive one entire message at a time. WebSocketHandler will reassemble the message from fragments if necessary.